# Jenkins build and deployment of spring boot client microservice fails because of config-server at https://localhost:8888 not present on maven build

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jenkins, deployment

My goal is to deploy 1 **spring-config-server** application AND 1 **spring-boot-client** application to the same Linux server machine.

**spring-boot-client application** port is **8081**
**spring-config-server application** port is **8888**

In Jenkins I created 2 jobs. First job is to build and deploy the **spring-config-server** application and start the jar. Second job is is to build and deploy the **spring-boot-client** application and start the jar.

I was able to build and deploy the **spring-config-server** application to the Linux machine. I can see it running at **localhost:8888**

[image]

**Problem :** Build task/job for **spring-boot-client** application in Jenkins is **failing** because when maven `clean install` is run, I believe that it tries to locate presence of a config server running at `localhost:8888`. I don't know if it's because of actuator dependency I added.

In Jenkins build console, this is what I get

> Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O
> error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/application/dev":
> Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)    at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:303)
> at
> org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.doLoad(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:118)
> ... 94 common frames omitted Caused by: java.net.ConnectException:
> Connection refused (Connection refused)

In the **spring-boot-client** app's `application.properties`, the only setting I have are these :

```
# ANT_PATH_MATCHER is added to avoid NULL error in SwaggerConfig
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER

server.port=8081

# Spring Config Server URL of Config Server Microservice :
spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888

# Environment configuration which you want to load :
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

In spring-boot-client's jenkins build job, this is what I have :

[image]

Now, theoretically, I believe that deploying 1 config-server and 1 client-app in the same linux machine should be possible. I just don't know how to properly configure it in Jenkins.

I have this spring cloud config client in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I have a copy of the spring-config-server app and spring-boot-client app in my local machine. I just start/run both and it works.

I am a beginner in Jenkins and I do everything in UI. This is just a build task with scp and ssh commands executed in shell to deploy.

I'd appreciate any help or comment.

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, Maven doesn't check your configuration service during the build phase, nor does the Spring Boot Maven plugin. My guess is that you have some test that uses Spring and that uses the default configured location (`http://localhost:8888`). So the solution would be to fix that test. Can you show the entire build output (or at least more than just a part of a stack trace)?

Comment: @g00glen00b, hey thanks! for your comment. After reading your comment and rechecking the log, I think you are probably right. I have to read further in the logs. On near end of the logs, I see some `junit` tests failing I'll come back here for update.